# PHP equivalent of Javascript "for(x in y)"

Tags: javascript, php

I am wondering what is the equivalent of "for in(x in y)" of javascript in PHP? I've seen this code from other website with the same functionalities of my program but i want it to be converted into php.

Like for this javascript code:

```
function get_tat_friends(){
    var ar_friends = []; ar_fr_info = [];
    FB.api('me/photos?type=uploaded&fields=likes,comments',function(data){
        obj = data['data'];
        for(x in obj){
          if(obj[x]['likes'] != null){
            obj_like = obj[x]['likes']['data'];
            for(y in obj_like){
              if(ar_friends[obj_like[y]['id']] == null){
                ar_friends[obj_like[y]['id']] = 1;
                ar_fr_info[obj_like[y]['id']] = obj_like[y]['name'];
              }else{
                ar_friends[obj_like[y]['id']] += 1;
                ar_fr_info[obj_like[y]['id']] = obj_like[y]['name'];
              }
            }
          }
          if(obj[x]['comments'] != null){
            obj_like = obj[x]['comments']['data'];
            for(y in obj_like){
              if(ar_friends[obj_like[y]['from']['id']] == null){
                ar_friends[obj_like[y]['from']['id']] = 1;
                ar_fr_info[obj_like[y]['from']['id']] = obj_like[y]['from']['name'];
              }else{
                ar_friends[obj_like[y]['from']['id']] += 2;
                ar_fr_info[obj_like[y]['from']['id']] = obj_like[y]['from']['name'];
              } 
            }
          }
        }
        ar_friends = getSortedKeys(ar_friends);
        //delete user_id
          var index = ar_friends.indexOf(user_id);
          if (index >= 0) {
            ar_friends.splice( index, 1 );
          }

        //call done function
        done_load_friends(ar_friends,ar_fr_info);
    })
}
```

I already tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
obj = data['data'];
for($x in obj){
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at PHP documentation **[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)** loop:

```
foreach(array_expression as $value){
    statement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an associative array, it's

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    ...
}
```

If you have an object, you can get an associative array of its public properties with [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php), so you can write:

```
foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $key => $value) {
    ...
}
```